# How to change div width with jQuery from 50 to 100% and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, width

I am working on test website (i am learning html+css) and now I need your help with something.

I have 3 divs with texts(width 50% each) and in upper left corner of every div i want to have image with "+" symbol. When user click on in, symbol + will change itself to - and width of div (just for that one div).

Good example is here on pic: http://i39.tinypic.com/9va7pz.png (but i want "-" symbol too)

Can someone shows me how to do that? I have no chance with JS (newbie).

Of course if it is possible to animate it (not only change width)

(sry for bad english - hope you will understand what i want)

Comment: Search for jQuery modal or lightbox plugins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your HTML should be something like this

```
<div><span class='changeSign'>+</span>some text here</div>
<div><span class='changeSign'>+</span>some text here</div>
<div><span class='changeSign'>+</span>some text here</div>
```

Then you can position your  with position:relative inside your

Your jQuery will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('span.changeSign').click(function(){
if ($(this).text() == '+'){
$(this).parent('div').css('width','100%');
    $(this).text('-');
}     else {
$(this).parent('div').css('width','50%');
    $(this).text('+');
}    

   });
});
```

wodking example - http://jsfiddle.net/ncXvM/

Answer (score 0):

```
    html:

        <div id='symbol'>+</div> // the "+" symbol, you'd like to click, you can change the + to a image.
        <div id='d1'></div>
        <div id='d2'></div>
        <div id='d3'></div>

js(with jquery):
    $('#symbol').click(function(){
       $(this).attr('id', 'sub')
       $(this).text('-') //if it's image, change the image
       $('#d1').css('width', '100%')
    });

   $('#sub').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', 'symbol')
       $(this).text('+') //if it's image, change back to "+" image
       $('#d1').css('width', '50%')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to just simply collapse-expand the `<div>`, I think this will do.

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse"><a>+</a><p>Some text...</p></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    if($(this).parent('div').attr('class') == 'collapse'){
        $(this).text('-')//if it's an image, replace it via .attr('src', 'url');
        .parent('div').width('100%').attr('class','expand')
    }else {
        $(this).text('+').parent('div').width('50%').attr('class','collapse')
    }   
});
```

if you want to add some animations just add CSS `transition` to your `<div>`

```
div { transition: width 0.5s linear;}
```

or with jQuery `.animate()`

```
.animate({width:'100%'},500);
```